# Rails - how to route to a nested resource when containing resource is not set

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know that in a nested resource, you have to pass the id of the containing resource for it to work.

However, I want to allow users to create a review for a product and specify the product within the form in the new view rather than actually pass it in in the route. So rather than being on a product and then review it, there would be a master review form where you can select any product within the form.

I am getting an error trying to do this and can't figure it out - what is the solution?

```
#error
No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"reviews"}    

#view
new_product_review_path

#controller
def new
    #@product = Product.new
    @review = Review.new
end

#routes.rb
resources :products do
    resources :reviews
end
```

Comment: BTW, why do you have @product = Product.new, in your action ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep reviews nested within products, but move the creation for reviews outside:

```
# routes.rb
resources :products do
  resources :reviews, except: [:new, :create]
end

resources :reviews, only: [:new, :create]
```

Then use `new_review_path` to create a new review.

If you wanted to have the option to create a review either attached to a particular product or not, drop the :except option for your nested review, and modify your controller action and form based on product_id.present?.

---

**EDIT**: (In response to the Zephyr's follow up question)

In the example above, I've specified that the `:new` and `:create` should only be accessible outside products, and not inside it by using the `:except` and `:only` options for reviews -- feel free to drop them if you'd like to be able to do anything with reviews regardless of whether it's nested or not. The only thing to be careful of then is that the same controller actions will handle the requests regardless of whether it's nested or not -- `reviews#index` will handle both `/reviews` and `/products/1/reviews`, for example -- so you'll need to make sure that your controller handles that properly. For example, using a before filter:

```
# users_controller.rb
before_filter :filter_by_product

def filter_by_product
  @parent_product = Product.find(params[:product_id]) if params[:product_id]
  @reviews = @parent_product ? @parent_product.reviews : Review.all
end

def new
  @review = @reviews.build
end

...
```

You may also need to make changes to your view based whether it's nested or not. For example, in your form to create a review, you could use a drop down of products if it's not nested or replace that with a hidden field with the `product_id` if it is.

Comment: Could I just add resources :reviews outside of the products block in the routes file AND keep it in there and thus have access to both the nested and unnested resource? I've seen this in other stackoverflow answers

Comment: Yep, nothing to stop you doing that, which is what I was pointing to at the end of my answer. In that case though, both paths will call the same controller action, so you need to make sure it (and possibly your views as well) behave appropriately. I've added a bit to my answer to expand on that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `namespace` thing to wrap your route with something else

Comment: I am not sure I understand, could you please be a bit more specific? Sorry just new to this.

Answer (score -1):

Move resources :reviews outside the block

```
resources :products
resources :reviews
```

and use

```
new_review_path
```

This way, your reviews are not tied down to any product.

Comment: Is there another way to fix it? For my application, reviews only make sense within the context of products, so it seems like an ideal situation to use nested routes...